# Knockout Js multiselect binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a collection of country-list bound in KnockoutJs DropDown list as follows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUYE1.png)

In knockoutJS, how to remove the country in all other country-lists as soon as that country is selected in one list?

Answer (score 0):

If you have all regions, you can dynamically determine which countries there are left to select. The logic:

- Collect all regions and their selections
- Remove the region you're currently looking at from that list
- Take all available countries
- Remove any country that is selected by another region from that list

In code:

```js
const getAvailableCountries = (allRegions, thisRegion) => {
  const otherRegions = allRegions.filter(r => r !== thisRegion);
  const inUseByOtherRegions = new Set(
    otherRegions.flatMap(r => r.selectedCountries())
  );
  
  return countries.filter(c => !inUseByOtherRegions.has(c));
}
```

The hard part is to obtain a reference to the "sibling regions". My suggestion is to use knockout's binding context for that:

```
data-bind="options: getAvailableCountries($parent.regions, $data)"
```

In a runnable example:

```js
const countries = [ "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5" ];
const regions = ["R1", "R2", "R3" ];

const getAvailableCountries = (allRegions, thisRegion) => {
  const inUseByOtherRegions = new Set(
    allRegions.flatMap(r => r === thisRegion
      ? []
      : r.selectedCountries()
    )
  );
  
  return countries.filter(c => !inUseByOtherRegions.has(c));
}

const vm = {
  regions: regions.map(
    regionId => ({
      regionId,
      
      getAvailableCountries,
      selectedCountries: ko.observableArray([])
    })
  )
}


ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: regions" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
  <div>
    <h2 data-bind="text: regionId"></h2>
    <select data-bind="
      options: getAvailableCountries($parent.regions, $data),
      selectedOptions: selectedCountries" size="5" multiple="true"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```